# Unable to connect using Telnet

Tags: windows, networking, telnet

I am unable to connect one of my friends computer using telnet. We are connected under the same network and Telnet is installed on both the computers. After using the command for establishing a connection, nothing happens. A black window appears and then a cursor starts blinking.

Even though we are under the same network, I am also unable to get a response while pinging his IP, though there's no issue accessing the internet from his end.

Does anyone knows the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check your Windows firewall to open incoming TCP Port 23 for Telnet. Also be sure not to confuse telnet server and client, which are installed seperately in windows features. ICMP Ping can also be filtered by Windows firewall, but this is not by default if both clients are connected to "private" network. Most of my writing is only true for the more up2date versions of Windows (e.g. NOT XP)

Comment: I think you should check your firewall settings if you are not able to ping it. Do you get your IP adresses via DHCP or is it a static adress, if its static i think you should also check if you are in the same subnet.

Comment: *"A black window appears and then a cursor starts blinking."* That, if I recall correctly, is the default behavior of Microsoft's telnet client when a connection has been established.

Comment: Yes, that's right but if you try to write some commands and run it, then it should behave like the way you want but in my case it just shows nothing, only the cursor moves. No matter what I type. I'm pretty sure Michael that a connection has not been established. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have a telnet server running on the 2nd machine? [Configuring Telnet Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754837(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: No I haven't, I will follow the link and configure the Telnet server on the 2nd machine. Thank you David.